# Answer posts prefixed with "This is a comment not an answer"

Tags: discussion

I think this is the fourth time this year where someone posts an answer with the statement, as in  [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63522477/sublime-text-3-bash-javac-command-not-found/63523271#63523271)

> This should be a comment, but I can't comment yet.

I flag it as "Not an answer" but the response is "Declined". Every single time this has happened including one where the answer was eventually removed by a moderator.

Why?

Comment: *"Sublime will print your current path variable (example). Make sure the paths are set correctly."* - This was the problem OP had, saying to check it is in the answer, what's not an answer about it?

Comment: In general, if I flag NAA, I add a comment first to explain why it is NAA. I assume that reviewers/mods see those before handling.

Comment: @halfer I did comment. The poster themself said "this is a comment"!

Comment: Just because they say it should be a comment doesn't mean it actually should. If someone isn't familiar enough with the site's rules to know not to write a comment as an answer, then assume they aren't familiar enough to judge whether something is an answer or not either. I don't know anything about Java or Sublime Text, but since the OP accepted it presumably it answered their question.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery So we should determine they don't know the difference between a comment and an answer, too?

Comment: Fair enough, Rob. I would say that in most cases I edit answers to remove this prefix - often something that is confessedly not an answer turns out to be fairly answerish once the waffle is removed.

Comment: @Rob So by your logic as soon as someone says "This should be a comment", that instantly makes it not an answer, _even when it answers the question_? - You have editing privileges, why not just edit it out?

Comment: @Rob No. You should judge the answer by its actual content, not by what someone (even the poster themselves) says about the content. The answer is clearly an answer when judged on its own merits, so simply edit the comment out and be done.

Comment: @Nick I give the benefit of the doubt that the person posting the comment knows what they're talking about.

Comment: @Rob So you also upvote an answer if it starts with "This answer is so good it should be upvoted by everyone"? No, you don't. You make your own judgement. Same with judging if the answer is an answer or not, the value judgement of someone else is irrelevant and should just be edited out.

Comment: I confess I haven't read the entire comment thread here, but... Don't go on auto-pilot when reviewing posts. Key phrases are useful to help you sniff out a problem, but you shouldn't flag on that basis. If the initial phrase is removed, ask yourself, *is this* now *an answer?* That's what the moderator who reviews your flag is going to ask themselves. They're not going to trigger on phrases, and you shouldn't, either. Not everyone understands the distinction between comments and answers, and that misunderstanding goes in both directions.

Comment: “If someone isn't familiar enough with the site's rules to know not to write a comment as an answer, then assume they aren't familiar enough to judge whether something is an answer or not either.” - but if if they believe it’s a comment shouldn’t it be treated as a comment?

Comment: @SecurityHound No. Likewise if I believe something I post in the Answer box to be an answer, it may be, but it doesn't mean it is. Same for Questions. This is why we review.

Answer (score 9):

Comments usually contain clarification requests, hints or remarks about side information that don't address directly the question.

But, if the *"this is a comment"* answer actually **answers** the question, it is wrong flagging it as NAA. The correctness of the answer is not relevant.

The action I suggest, instead, is just to edit it, removing the "this is a comment" statement. Then, if you feel that the resulting answer is too concise and could be improved with more details, encouraging the user to expand a good answer in order to make it a great one (in a comment) would complete the task.

Comment: I'd add to this that NAA is not appropriate for things that are terrible or wrong answers - it is for me-too questions, posts that are just requests for clarifications, etc. If something is terrible you can try LQ if it is available, but otherwise just downvote.