# Is an answer that says that other answers are wrong not an answer?

Tags: discussion, not-an-answer

In the First Posts queue I recently encountered [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64930087/) that states that two other answers, including the accepted one, are wrong. To prove this, the author gave some counter examples, and noted that they would have commented if they had sufficient reputation.

Usually I flag answers which should be comments as NAA, but this one is quite extensive and (as far as I can tell) correctly points out flaws in other answers<sup>1</sup>. It would probably be undesirable to lose that information. However, it also does not answer the question itself, so would qualify for an NAA flag.

After a short discussion in SOCVR I decided to raise an NAA flag. Anyway, I figured that it would be interesting to get some more input on this corner case, to have a guideline whenever this happens again.

So, my question: How do we handle answers by new contributors that point out valid flaws in other answers?

- Simply delete them as NAA?
- Leave a comment on the flawed answers on the author's behalf?
- Mod flag?
- Something else?

---

<sup>1</sup>Although in this specific case the question is a bit unclear, and leaves room for interpretation: Is a path allowed to contain the same node more than once?

Comment: Related: [When to flag an answer as “not an answer”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265552/11682469)

Comment: i.... would have to agree with your assessment due to the fact that the answer doesn't actually provide a solution. but if their claims have merit... it wouldn't feel right to me to just delete it and leave it at that.

Comment: so, definitely downvote the wrong answers (if they are in fact wrong), maybe leave comments on them explaining why they are wrong if that can be done in a comment, *then* deal with the NAA

Comment: The answer being discussed includes a comment saying to come here rather than comment on the answer itself. Does that include comments on the validity of one of the answer's claims rather than a comment discussing the general appropriateness of the answer as an answer? If the answer were shown to be itself incorrect, then it would be easier to decide to just delete it. I don't know if that's a good or bad thing, as it might tear down the poster child of the larger discussion. - It doesn't seem like my comment would belong here.

Comment: “In the First Posts queue I recently encountered an answer that states that two other answers, including the accepted one, are wrong.” - Sounds like the answer should have been submitted as commentary

Comment: @Steve Technical comments on the veracity of the answer are still appropriate there. My point is to have “meta” discussions on the suitability of the answer and/or whether it should be deleted *here*, on the Meta site. I improved the wording on my original comment.

Comment: "...noted that they would have commented if they had sufficient reputation." That seems to be the key here. Just help them by copying the content into comment(s) giving attribution and thank them for posting then flag for NAA and tell them that unfortunately an answer is not the right place.

Comment: In the very special case that there is no solution to the question this answer would actually be the only legitimate answer and all the other answers would be wrong. Was there at least one correct answer?

Comment: @Trilarion Yet the "answer" does not say "there is no answer". It says "these two are not answers". It does not say whether in principle there is or is-not a correct answer.

Comment: I was not aware the answer was under discussion on Meta; I would not have deleted it if I was as to not disrupt the debate. So, sorry about that.

Comment: However, I personally still think this is Not An Answer and thus agree with the flags.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi That leaves us with the slightly paradoxical: If it would say that there is no answer, it would be an (attempt to) answer.

Comment: Basically the shortcomings of other answers are also well placed at even other (more correct) answers. They could also be an edit to another answer. Basically if I write an answer and there are already other answers I must motivate somehow why we need another answer and pointing out flaws in other answers is always nice to emphasize the merit of another answer (if that other answer doesn't suffer from the same problems too).

Comment: Sometimes, the commentary needed to show that something is wrong is too big for even a series of comments, and code in comments cannot be formatted for legibility.  In such circumstances, providing an 'answer' that is an extended comment makes sense to me.  Clearly, this would be better still if there was also a proposed solution — or a pointer to another answer than those critiqued that provided an acceptable solution.

Comment: Really???? Answers should never be extended comments. How come everybody has forgotten the very simple and fundamental tenets of this Q&A platform? Baffling.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Problem is here that the contribution is kind of valuable and too long for a single comment. The question is what best to do with it. I'm tempted to edit it in the respective answers. But an edit to an answer saying why this answer is wrong looks a bit strange either.

Comment: I think that people got on the wrong footing because the partial answer discussed here started with "I meant to comment but have to put this in an answer due to insufficient rep". That's nice and modest but let people read the answer in the wrong light. So I took the liberty and simply edited it away.

Comment: It's not an answer - and OP admits it isn't an answer. But after reviewing the edit history I see that we've already had a delete/undelete battle between two mods so I have little hope this thing can be removed. Well, there's lots of crap content on SO - we can just add this non-answer to the pile and move on.

Comment: I find it quite incomprehensible that people are allowed to answer a question, but are not allowed to dispute someone else's answer. SO's social engineering drives me crazy.

Comment: Much as we [don't](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295628/improve-edit-answer-with-single-character-but-critical#comment436393_295628) make or [approve trivial edits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/292243/3648282), we don't allow *answers* which don't attempt to answer the question. **IF** that should be changed then suggest that, get the upvotes, and [ask for the wording of the Help to be changed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/356127/282094); let's not make up our own inconsistent rules on the fly, then ask afterwards if that's OK.

Comment: I have never understood why anyone should be allowed to answer but not to comment. It's simply forcing them to submit their comments as if they were answers.

Answer (score 55):

"Not an Answer" is the wrong flag in any case.  "Not an answer" is for things like "I have the same problem, any solution?"

If you're casting a moderator flag, the implication is that you want a *moderator* to take action on this particular answer, rather than leaving it to the community.  The only reasonable response that a moderator can take to a "not an answer" flag is to delete the answer.

So the question you have to ask yourself is, "does this answer harm the site enough that it must be forcibly removed by a moderator?"  I would argue that it doesn't.

Comment: I think an answer that says other answers are wrong can't be considered NAA, at all. A mod flag might be innapropriate as well, only because it's an answer. If one doesn't like the answer, they can downvote, but not flag.

Comment: @exnihilo not only on the flag that condition is there, it's also [on the help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers): Answers that do not fundamentally answer the question may be removed. This includes answers that are: **commentary on** the question or **other answers**

Comment: @exnihilo Except that they went out of their way to inform about problems with the other posts. The information is useful for users that find those others posts. Language layering seems destructive. Removing it makes Stack worse, not better.

Comment: I agree Robert. I would go further though, beyond "does this cause harm" to *this is actually a valid answer*, because it does answer the question by stating what not to do. Is that *useful*? Well, that is what votes are for, not deletions.

Comment: @exnihilo Even "don't do it like this: <code>" is not very useful. Answers need to say what you *should* do, not what you shouldn't!

Comment: @exnihilo In no way was I trying to discredit anyone, the answers which I had pointed out as incorrect were upvoted and accepted. Furthermore, the examples given in my "answer" are quite relevant to the original question posted. I'll add a disclaimer to my post nonetheless.

Comment: It's straight up not an answer, categorically, and if the threshold for curation & moderation is "it must materially harm the site" then really what the heck are we all bothering for?

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings: You sound frustrated.  Don't be.  Moderation is always a value judgement; if it weren't, what would be the point?  Slavish adherence to rules?

Comment: I mean, sure, we could all just ignore the quality controls that we've spent the last 11 years putting in place, so that we don't appear to be "slavishly adhering to rules". I don't know when or why it became cool to "do the wrong thing" just for appearances' sake, but yay I suppose.

Comment: We call that a "slippery slope fallacy."

Comment: This is not a forum. If you have reservations of other posts you should comment on them, not posting another answer that should be a solution to the issue the question is about.

Comment: Moderators can also convert an answer into a comment, which is usually the desirable outcome

Comment: I don't see how my comment counts as an invocation of the slippery slope fallacy. At all.

Answer (score 32):

This is borderline NAA (because it maybe should've been a comment), but I'm going to argue that it's not.

While they don't provide a solution to the original question, it's still pointing out legitimate information what will help the OP solve the problem. Ideally, "the accepted answer is wrong!" answers will also provide guidance on what the OP should do instead (I actually did that recently in a case where the accepted answer recommended a dangerous practice), but even without that it provides at least *some* useful information to help the OP solve the problem.

That being said, I think that this falls under the [partial answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) category.

Comment: Yes. The "contains legitimate information" pertinent to the question (and thus potentially helping the OP towards a solution!) is the important bit. Therefore it *does* constitute a partial answer. It is also (if correct, which I cannot tell) quite useful to readers. The OP may have hurt his case by saying he would have commented if he could. In fact, since comments are ephemeral and ancillary information only, a comment may actually be insufficient for such substantial information. Reminds me of the "positive results bias" in scientific publications: Failed research is rarely published.

Comment: Well said.  To put it very tersely: "answer" does not imply "solution."

Comment: I like @WayneConrad's succinct rule. There are many useful contributions that are more than comments on the question but less than solutions to the problem: for example, advice on a strategy for diagnosing the problem. However, pointing out flaws in an existing answer should ideally go in a comment, and it's just bizarre that we allow people to answer a question and don't allow them to critique existing answers; it's bound to lead to this kind of consequence.

Answer (score 29):

I see that other posters have advocated the "never delete anything good" approach to SO. So I will play devil's advocate and represent a strict interpretation:

This is NAA. It is not an answer to the question. It is not a partial answer to the question. Instead it is a sign post to information in another place. That is a NAA as described [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265553/1456253). The correct place for such information is as a comment on each answer.

Alternatively, stating such facts and then *also* giving an answer would be good as well and probably the best outcome. But this requires OP to provide some bit of an answer in there.

Personally if I ran across such an answer, I would, however, not immediately vote NAA, even if it is one. Instead I would try to get OP to provide at least a partial solution.

Comment: Hopefully the author of that answer will respond positively to the comment requesting them to include an actual solution in their answer

Comment: Im wondering, why is the question even on SO? it is NOT a programming question (i.e about a specific implementation). It is suitable for CS stack exchange or math SE.

Comment: @PM2Ring I am the author of that post (It seems now I have enough reputation to comment), I have no efficient solution to the question asked, in fact I came across the question while searching for an efficient solution. My "answer" is quite big, which I don't think would fit in a comment.

Comment: @helperFunction Ah. In that case, we *do* have a problem, as you've probably gathered from the answers & comments here. You do need to include *some* kind of solution to the OP's question for your post to qualify as an answer. It doesn't have to be the most efficient solution, but it *should* correctly answer "whether there is a path from u to w that passes through v". But note that we don't usually delete answers that are technically wrong, we downvote them.

Comment: ...or add that there is some degree of suspicion that there does not exist an efficient approach to the problem... thus breathing life into @MisterMiyagi's paradox!

Answer (score 11):

Even though I'm otherwise sympathetic to an answerer who falls in this category, one issue I do see is this: For comments on other people's posts, 50 reputation is required.  If they lack that reputation and are doing this to circumvent that requirement, then that kind of defeats the purpose of having such a requirement.  On these grounds alone, I would say it does fall into the category of NAA.

However code11's suggestion to simply hold back for a bit and to see if the OP can resolve the issue, before a flag is raised, is probably a pretty solid way to handle it, in cases where it's still a valuable contribution.

Comment: Just because someone thinks they contribution is a comment, doesn't make it one. And the reverse is also true. See [Answer posts prefixed with “This is a comment not an answer”](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402287/answer-posts-prefixed-with-this-is-a-comment-not-an-answer) I mean I could start this with "This is not a comment".

Comment: You need [50 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) to comment everywhere.

Comment: “For comments on other people's posts, 50 reputation is required.” - And? The fact you need 50 reputation to submit a comment doesn’t give a user without the privilege to submit a comment latitude to submit commentary as an answer.

Comment: So you'd rather lose the information the person can provide instead of having it in the wrong type of post? The whole problem would be avoided if the stupid rep requirement was removed. Comments can be flagged after all.

Comment: @Jakub - This commentary was submitted as an answer, different rules exist on answers, a lot easier to delete actual unnecessary commentary, compared to commentary submitted as an answer.  Most often the commentary submitted as answer isn’t actually helpful.  The fact the commentary submitted as an answer this time was helpful, just goes to show, it probably should have actually been submitted as a comment.  It would have resulted in the existing answers being improved.  Commentary submitted as an answer won’t notify the answer author of the feedback to their answer

Comment: @SecurityHound If I'm understanding your first comment right, I'm saying the same thing you are.

Comment: @SecurityHound But the user did NOT have the rep to submit a comment. They could not have followed the rules because the rules prevented them from doing so. That their post is further criticized just adds insult to injury.

Comment: They were not forced to break the rules by submitting a comment as an answer.  Ironically if they had just answered the question instead of commenting on other answers they would have earned the privilege to submit commentary

Answer (score 5):

**It is quite clearly not an answer.**

Feedback on existing answers goes in comments under the existing answer. That's what comments are for. Period; end of story.

Just because somebody doesn't have enough reputation to post comments yet, doesn't mean they get a free pass on putting their comment in the wrong place instead. It should be self-evident that the purpose of the rep threshold is to make newcomers *watch and learn* how the Q&A model works before contributing, *not* to make newcomers post in the incorrect place instead.

Although, from what I've seen of people's opinions of both the cited answer and of the purpose of comments more generally, I'd argue that *watching and learning* is increasingly unlikely to result in any actual wisdom these days.

It's really quite simple:

- If you have an answer to the posed question, a solution to the posed problem, *write it an answer*. It will get peer reviewed, sorted by votes, put in review queues as needed, and all those other lovely things that underpin the Q&A model that is *the whole purpose of this site* as compared to random forums.
- If you have commentary on an existing answer, or a request for clarification on a question, *write a comment*.

If you can't do either of those things, either due to time constraints, or the question being closed, or not having enough rep to comment, then that's fine: *simply don't do it*.

That's it. Only that. Nothing more. No ifs, no buts, no hints, no tips, no maybes. This isn't hard.

Comment: I appreciate you saying what should have been done.  I think the most important part you point out is that answers are peer reviewed and commentary really isn’t.  So by submitting commentary as an answer you really gunk up the gears in the system

Comment: @SecurityHound 100%! The design decisions for this site weren't arbitrary. I'm not clear on why it seems a majority of users nowadays proudly wish to circumvent or subvert them.

Comment: Couldn't a moderator convert the answer to a comment or something?

Answer (score 5):

There is a semantic difference between an *answer* and a *solution,* and I feel that confusing the two is what fuels this discussion.

Showing that several different apparent solutions are not viable constitutes *a partial answer,* even though it is not *a solution.* The information is pertinent and may help the OP and other readers finding a solution.

By contrast, the NAA flag is, like Robert says, for contributions which do not substantially deal with the subject of the question.

Comment: This is incorrect, the help page says "answer _the_ question", this is commenting on the correctness of other answers.

Comment: @Braiam I think you understand "to answer" as "to provide a solution". The OP is under the same semantic haze. You can (partially) answer a question *without providing a solution!* Ideally in that case, you'd prove that there is none, or provide one, but both may be hard; it is certainly a partial answer to *refute* some erroneous attempts at a solution. There is a similar well-known and recently oft-criticized positive result bias in academic publishing: Failed attempts, although they would be valuable contributions to science, are too often not published.

Comment: @Braiam More concretely: "commenting on [here: refuting] the correctness of other answers" certainly is part of the the process to "answer the question". If you can refute *all* possible solution attempts it is a complete answer; if you can only refute some, it's a partial answer.

Comment: I think answers should effectively contain solutions, otherwise they aren't answers. Simply dealing with the subject of the question is not enough. Even comments can deal with the subject of the question but may not be a solution. This should indeed have been a comment.

Answer (score 1):

It is not an answer.

The author of that "answer" explicitly gave a disclaimer that said:

> Note: This post doesn't answer the question posted, ... I had originally intended this "answer" as a comment, but I didn't have the reputation to comment at that time.

So the author agrees, now what?

You can comment to the author and ask them to provide at least some info to help solve the actual question *(though it's pretty unlikely they have any, or why wouldn't they have added it in the first place?)*. If you're feeling generous and don't want what seems like a valuable post to be disqualified, you may add the info for them *(that is, again, if you have any)*.

A different approach:

If the author agrees that the answer should've been a comment in the first place; you can offer to comment for them, giving credits like:

> From @helperFunction The below counter example is incorrect, see the comment by Steve. I have provided another counter example after this one...

And then they can delete the comment post themselves.

Or if by the time you see the post, the author has reached the commenting privilege, remind them about their "answer" and ask them to change it into a comment.

---

If you decide to flag such an answer, there's a good chance that your flag would get declined *(adding to your declined flag statistics)* given this case is pretty controversial. I suggest flagging and then proposing for more users to flag it in the [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers), where you can explain your case.

---

About the "never delete anything good" approach... there are *millions* of such "good" comments! If they were to become answers, should we just leave them be? I think not.

EDIT:

> Just a small note of clarification: The SOCVR chatroom isn't really the place to ask others to raise NAA flags on posts (because one such flag has much the same effect as any number). However, if you feel strongly enough, and the post has a net negative vote score, you can use SOCVR to request delete votes on such posts. But you'd be expected to provide a good reason and be prepared to argue your case. – Adrian Mole

Comment: @AdrianMole Oh my god -- do we have a meta meta where we can discuss whether your comment is in fact a partial answer!? ;-)

Comment: There's probably a chatroom just for that, @Peter.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is commenting about the correctness of other answers. Flag a moderator so it's moved as comment of each answer or just deleted.

> Answers that do not fundamentally answer the question may be removed. This includes answers that are:
>
> - commentary on the question or **other answers**

https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers

Comment: I don't think it should be deleted, as 1. it does provide some useful information, even though I don't like it, and 2. mods don't really need to get involved imo. Lastly, can moderators convert answers to comments when the answerer has less than 50 reputation?

Comment: @10Rep ["Answers that do not fundamentally answer the question may be removed. This includes answers that are: commentary on the question or other answers"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: *"may be removed"* - agree, once wrong answers it refers are deleted. Until then it *adds* valuable information and while [it's not a solution](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/403062/1997232), it's an expert opinion on a subject, which should be kept for a while. Think of value of this answer to visitors. It's *higher* than other (wrong) answers.

Comment: @Sinatr if the other answers didn't exist, would that answer be capable of standing on its own? That's why answering the question asked is a hard requirement. Otherwise why have comments and answers as separated posts?

Comment: Most controversial post I've seen with +21/-21

Answer (score -5):

If it doesn't directly address the question, by definition it doesn't answer it so therefore no it's not an answer.

That's not the root problem though. The root problem is that people have constructive things to say but the reputation scoring system is preventing them from contributing in an appropriate manner.

The real question is which is more beneficial?

1. To allow people to contribute even if they haven't jumped through all the hoops, potentially allowing noise through at the same time
2. To enforce the hoops, while giving people headaches who are new to the site

Comment: Number 2. Yeah, definitely number 2.

Comment: It seems that there must be a third option...