# Critique of Question Facts as an Answer

Tags: discussion, answers, specific-answer

I was going through the Late Answers review queue when I saw this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67372374/15073477) - it is now deleted.

> I think that 6107310094082 it is not a valid South African id number. Checksum is only 1 digit and the number 2 is wrong. You need to use Luhn algorithm for checksum.

It seems like the answerer was merely critiquing the facts in the question rather than providing a solution. My best guess for this behavior is that the answerer is using the answer as a method of commenting to the OP, and given their current reputation, I can see why since they still haven't obtained the privilege to comment.

My question is, is this flaggable? If so, would I flag it as "not an answer" or something else? If not, then is there some other nuanced meaning that I'm simply missing?

**Note:** This is different from:
[Is an answer that says that other answers are wrong not an answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/403026/is-an-answer-that-says-that-other-answers-are-wrong-not-an-answer) because the answer is mainly pointing out facts mentioned in the question (not the answers) that are wrong.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is an answer that says that other answers are wrong not an answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/403026/is-an-answer-that-says-that-other-answers-are-wrong-not-an-answer). If not, then it's at least very related.

Comment: It is indeed similar, but I feel like there's a slight difference, since the answerer briefly mentioned how a different algorithm should be used. However, the answerer mostly wrote about how the ID should be "formatted" (for lack of a better word) differently.

Comment: Looks like an answer to me. Especially the "You need to use Luhn algorithm for checksum." part

Comment: Check [this guide](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288505/1426539) and see what option you believe should apply to this answer. Regarding "flagging", [this other post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265552/1426539) might come  handy.

Comment: Honestly, I don't think it really counts as an answer because it seems like the answerer wasn't really all that thorough about it, only providing a suggestion for the algorithm to implement for only part of the question rather than all the aspects of the ID mentioned in the question.

Comment: Check the second link in my previous comment. Being "thorough" is not a requisite for something to be considered "an answer". But you can always vote and/or comment. Flagging is not your only option.

Comment: That's fair. I'd wager what made me question it more than usual was the fact that the majority of the answer was about the facts of the question instead. It didn't really seem like the answer would bring any positive net benefit.

Comment: "*It didn't really seem like the answer would bring any positive net benefit*" sounds like a downvote reason, rather than a flag reason.

Comment: The answer looks suspiciously like a comment, though. I'd be inclined to flag NAA, but the case is borderline - so if don't want to risk it being declined, don't flag. But the answer is certainly of low quality, even if it is an answer, though (downvote reason).

Comment: @Yatin As somewhat of an SME, I can attest that the answer says "apples" when the question asks for "oranges" (continuing Shog's venerable tradition of fruit analogy). The question is simply asking how to parse a numeric string in JS, but the answer talks about checksum algorithms. The OP does not need to verify the correctness of the ID.

Comment: Remember that a poor, weak, outright crappy, or so-bad-my-eyes-bled-and-my-IQ-dropped answer is still an answer. Downvote the sucker and move on. If the answer is of the eye-bleeding variety and you have a delete vote to spare, consider using it.

Comment: It could be a frame challenge. Not all frame challenges really work well.

Comment: Could you briefly define what a "frame challenge" is?

Comment: FWIW I read that as a comment, not an answer. I would have at the bare minimum converted to comment myself.

Comment: @Machavity While I'm aware that some moderators would do what you've said (yourself included obviously), my understanding is that a NAA flag should not be raised for this answer. Would you mind reviewing my answer? If the reasons I listed for not raising NAA are incorrect/incomplete, or a NAA flag is actually recommended here, I'd be happy to edit my answer.

Comment: @PerplexingParadox A frame challenge is an attack on one or more of the assumptions in the question. Basically you say that the question is not meaningful as such. For example: "In Python there is no if statement. How can I achieve something similar as a workaround?" An answer would be "Do X". A frame challenge would be: "It's not true, in Python there is an if statement. The question therefore doesn't make sense."

Comment: @Trilarion I'd agree it's a frame challenge, but it's not even related to the programming aspect of the question, simply about how the IDs are calculated.

Comment: @PerplexingParadox [What's a frame challenge?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6842)

Comment: There used to be a "should be a comment" flag, where the moderators can convert the answer to a comment. The example in question seems like an ideal case for that.

Comment: @ClausJørgensen Was there a big reason why that specific flag was removed? (Too niche? Hard to judge? Etc.)

Comment: @PerplexingParadox looks like it's still there, I just didn't notice the rewording. The "not an answer" option suggests it should be used for answers that "should be a comment".

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From the guidance in [How should I get started reviewing Late Answers and First Posts?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288505) the linked answer seems to fall squarely in this category

> In *either queue*, if you see an **answer** that:
>
> - Is wrong, generally a lousy hack, barely addresses the question, or otherwise well below par:
>
>   - Downvote; comment if practical.

So I suggest leaving a comment explaining why the answer is bad, and downvoting it. If you have the privilege to delete answers (awarded at 20k), and the answer is eligible for deletion (score < 0), you can do that as well.

---

I suggest not raising a flag, and *especially* don't raise a "Not an answer" flag. Note that the text of the answer is pretty much all that a moderator sees. Faced with the text

> I think that 6107310094082 it is not a valid South African id number. Checksum is only 1 digit and the number 2 is wrong. You need to use Luhn algorithm for checksum.

I have to say that this is definitely an answer, and the last sentence even provides a solution.

- Is it a good answer? No, but it's still an answer.
- Is it correct? No, but moderators don't judge the technical correctness of an answer.
- Does it answer the question? No, but moderators don't necessarily even look at the question, and it's entirely possible that this answers *some* question on the site.

Comment: "...and it's entirely possible that this answers some question on the site." This is just a comment and I know there was a discussion about it but everyone has to draw a line somewhere. I guess there will always be answers that are so little of an answer that it's difficult really justifying their existence. It's entirely possible we don't really need 99.9% of those answers.

Comment: @Trilarion That's a fair point, and my own standard for what answers are worth keeping around are definitely higher than what is covered by NAA, but my advice against raising that flag is based on other discussions, as well as reports of what kind of answers NAA flags get declined on. And to clarify, I'm not suggesting the answer is worth keeping, but the mechanism for that would be deletion by curators with the privilege, not deletion by moderators in response to a NAA flag.

Comment: _"If you have the privilege to delete answers (awarded at 20k), and the answer is eligible for deletion (score < -1)"_ -- the criteria is score < 0. I.e. any negatively-voted answer can be deleted. That said, I will note that there is some dispute as to whether deleting answers simply because of low quality/inaccuracy is permitted; I've seen (and received) feedback from a moderator claiming that only things which are offensive, spam, or otherwise just not an answer are eligible for deletion. YMMV.

Comment: @PeterDuniho You're right about the score < 0. Fixed, thanks. Regarding deletion of low quality/inaccurate answers, I think the constraints you listed only apply to "recommending deletion" via review, and flagging for deletion by mods. AFAIK, trusted users are permitted to delete content as they see fit; I have voted to delete answers that are incorrect, or even actively misleading, and that's something that's done in SOCVR as well. If you can link to some reference saying this is not permitted, I'd appreciate that a lot.

Comment: _"I think the constraints you listed only apply to "recommending deletion""_ -- moderation is an individual affair, so it's certainly possible for a moderator to do something contrary to the norm. But: I have had at least one post I voted to delete undeleted by a moderator _and_ received feedback at the same time saying that my vote to delete was a violation of policy. This experience directly contradicts the view that _"trusted users are permitted to delete content as they see fit"_.

Comment: @PeterDuniho That's very interesting, I can't really say I've heard that happening before. I'm very curious what policy might have been violated by your voting to delete. Would you be willing to share a link to that particular answer and/or the exact message that you got from the moderator? The undeletion by itself doesn't mean anything other than that the mod disagreed with your assessment; that certainly happens, and mods are users who can cast votes as they see fit as well.

Comment: I wouldn't mind. But it did not happen recently and I don't keep records of that sort of thing, so it be prohibitively time-consuming for me to figure out exactly what post it was. I don't even have a copy of the actual message anywhere (it was sent via email and deleted permanently by now). I do realize that the feedback I received conflicted with other site activity, including the automated scripts that delete posts which are abandoned or otherwise appear not useful. I'm just sharing my experience to make clearer that users are not always given carte blanche when it comes to delete votes.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Sure, don't worry about digging it up. The experience you had is useful to know, even if the details are unclear, so thanks for that. I'll try digging into this to see if there's any reference for what sorts of deletions are, or aren't, permitted for trusted users. There are probably users hanging around in SOCVR who would be able to shed some insight into the matter :)

Comment: Do moderators really not look at the question when evaluating "Not an answer" flags? If so, it's really bad, because the formulation of the flag does imply the need for context to evaluate it: _"This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question"_. If an answer doesn't attempt to answer _the_ question it's posted for, even if it answers some other question, it does qualify for this flag.

Comment: @Ruslan NAA flags can be quite tricky, to some extent because different moderators handle things differently. I believe there are mods who will look at the question to evaluate a NAA, but there are also those who don't. The question is not shown automatically when evaluating a NAA flag, so it *is* additional work to look at the question, and some mods prefer their NAA flags to be on answers that are *obviously* not answers. Unfortunately, what's *obvious* or not to any given moderator varies  as well.

Comment: @Ruslan There's also a [guideline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185073) under "Rules of thumb", that says "If you can’t determine whether or not it’s an answer *without looking at the question* it supposedly answers, explain the problem in a comment below the answer.". That being said, moderators are also *not* guaranteed to look at the comments on a post when evaluating it, and this goes for NAA flags as well. I tend to err on the side of assuming something is not obvious, and raising custom flags in those cases (where applicable).

Comment: The problem with your recommendation is that some moderators will mark the flag as "declined - Using standard flags helps us prioritize problems and resolve them faster. Please familiarize yourself with the list of standard flags [...]".

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel To clarify, I'm *not* suggesting that a custom flag (or any flag) be raised for the linked answer. I assume you're referring to my previous comment, where I mentioned raising custom flags. I was just pointing out that custom flags should be raised when the issue is not obvious, but as I also mentioned, only *where applicable*. The linked answer is not one of those cases.

Comment: Eh? Faced with that text alone when doing delete-review, I'd simply be bemused and make no conclusion. I'd then go check the question... after which I would have decided that it's a comment, not an answer. I would have delete-voted it and anyone who had placed a "not an answer" flag did so correctly & will get their "flag was helpful" note.

Comment: @Lundin True, but that assumes that the answer gets deleted *before* it gets handled by a moderator. If it gets handled by a moderator, they may not do what you would when doing delete-review, and not look at the question, potentially resulting in a declined NAA flag.

Comment: @cigien I very much doubt that we have any moderators that are that inexperienced with delete reviews. Also this kind of crap is meant to be handled by the masses, it's a waste of resources to have diamond mods doing such reviews.

Answer (score -1):

This is straightforwardly a comment on the question and not an answer. The same problem could be easily formulated with a different example or no example at all; the example is not in any way essential to the question stated.

Since the remark doesn’t actually answer the question, it should have been posted as a comment instead. Moderators can easily convert a non-answer into a comment; as such, flagging as ‘not an answer’ is entirely appropriate here.